# How do we manage sessions and connection using OpenTok?

Tags: session, opentok, tokbox

For example, if I have 20 conversations in my app that correspond to 20 different session Ids which I get from my app server.

Let's assume that the sessionIDs are 1 to 20.

Now can someone let me know how I will be notified if another user initiates a video call on conversation 15 (Session Id 15) so I can connect to same session and subscribe to the stream.

Answer (score 0):

OpenTok QA staff here,

You can just connect to that sessionId, and listen for the onStreamCreated event. This event will be triggered when a publisher starts sending media to the session. Then, you can create a subscriber, and receive the stream.

Please, find more info and details here:

https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/publish-stream/js

https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/subscribe-stream/js/

Answer (score 0):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

As Fran mentioned, you can connect to the session ID and listen to the `streamCreated` event to start subscribing. However, to know if someone is in the session without being present in the session, you can set up [session monitoring](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/session-monitoring/) which allows you to receive the following events through a callback on your server:

- `connectionCreated`
- `connectionDestroyed`
- `streamCreated`
- `streamDestroyed`

You can then use these events to connect to the appropriate session and start subscribing to the specific stream.

Comment: how I can i achieve if no one is receiving call then disconnect publishing